# Как сделать box в который будут выводиться рандомные числа от -1000 до 1000 js

Tags: javascript

Как сделать box в который будут выводиться рандомные числа от -1000 до 1000 js

Answer (score 1):

так ?

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

setInterval( function(){
  box.innerHTML = randomInteger(-1000, 1000); 
}, 1000)

 function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
  return Math.floor(rand);
} 

box.innerHTML = randomInteger(-1000, 1000)
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector(".box span").textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2001) - 1000;
}, 500);
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box span {
  margin: auto;
  font-size:x-large;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><span>TEST</span></div>
```

Comment: @Leks Идея правильная, формула - нет.

Comment: @Leks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @Leks Теперь это такое же выражение, как у меня. Было бы странно, если бы я сказал, что оно неправильное :).